# Can users access files directly from iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, filesystems

I am a beginner in iOS development.

I'm copying this by looking at an example of making a file.

```swift
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fileName = "Test"
        let DocumentDirURL =  try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("")

        let writeString = "write test sting"
        do {
            try writeString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch _ as NSError {
            print("write error")
        }
    }
```

My question is that my current code is making and saving a file in document directory.

1. Can user see this file with user own eyes?
2. And is there anything else that I need to have permission to execute
   this code?

This is an old `Swift` code. If there is a code that has a better way, please recommend it to me. Please help me a lot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem with using the `documentDirectory` is, yes, it's "possible" for a user to see the files in it, assuming the App provides the appropriate settings in it's `info.plist`.  Event if you don't want to expose the contents of the App to the user yet, you should avoid putting files in the document's directory, unless it really makes sense to do so, it will save you lots of time and effort later on if you do choose to expose the App's documents

Comment: Thanks you for your help @MadProgrammer Is the document directory you're talking about basically the Documents folder on your iOS phone?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am asking because I don't use an iPhone, but where is the document directory on the iPhone? Is it in internal memory like Android?

Comment: It's not.  The `documentDirectory` in this context is contextual to the App itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a path of the directory you wanna saveit

```
 let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

    if let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as? NSURL {
        // This is where the database should be in the documents directory
        let finalDatabaseURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("items.db")

        if finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) {
            // The file already exists, so just return the URL
            return finalDatabaseURL
        } else {
            // Copy the initial file from the application bundle to the documents directory
            if let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("items", withExtension: "db") {
                let success = fileManager.copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: finalDatabaseURL, error: nil)
                if success {
                    return finalDatabaseURL
                } else {
                    println("Cant found!")
                }
            } else {
                println("Couldn't find !")
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Couldn't get documents directory!")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @ArunPrasath It's a code that asks you to create a directory path that you want to save, but isn't my code already stored in the directory path?

Comment: it ll be stored in mobile that users can see by the file manager or otherwise we ll see it in the DB browser by using simulator Thanks @hongdevelop

Comment: um..OK @ArunPrasath After creating a path using your code, how should I apply it using my code? I'm a beginner of iOS and I don't know how to do it.